# Jquery: check if fieldset are empty

Tags: jquery

I need to check if any fieldset in the DOM is empty. Empty means that it has not text inside (legend is not inside). For example, this is an empty fieldset:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>a1</legend>
    <input type="hidden" name="x" value="y">
</fieldset>
```

It has no text nodes except inside *legend*.

Until now I was using this JQuery to check this condition:

```
    if ($(this).find(":not(legend)").text().trim() == '') {
    ...
    }
```

Note this comes from a .each() call. The problem is that now I've found that it doesn't works on nested fieldsets like this:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>a</legend>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>a1</legend>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>a2</legend>
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
```

In this case the jquery expression:

```
$("fieldset").find(":not(legend)").text().trim()
```

returns "a1 a2" as a result. What's the problem? [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/navi2000/NKyBZ/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("fieldset").find(":not(legend):not(fieldset)").text().trim()
```

you need to take into account fieldsets which have fieldsets. What is happening is the selector is saying "this fieldset has a fieldset and since you are looking for anything that is not a legend this is a valid element". It then finds the text in that element which is the a1 and the a2

Update:
per your comment below, try this solution.

```
$('fieldset').filter(function(index) {
  return $(this)
            .clone()
            .find("legend,fieldset")
            .remove()
            .end()
            .text()
            .trim()
            .length > 0;
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but surely I explained very bad my problem. Look this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/navi2000/NKyBZ/3/ In this case, the alert says there is no text, but really there is some text in a inner fieldset. In this case, the jquery sentence should return "Some text"

Comment: I've update my solution to fix your problem. I hope it helps!

Comment: I'm confused as to what you want the expect result to be. Currently my solution returns only the nested fieldset with the "some text" in it. Is this not the desired result? If you want the parent fieldset AND the nested fieldset simply remove the "fieldset" text in the .find() selector

Comment: Opss.. sorry! You are right. I don't aware that the sentence was returning an object and applied directly on my app that expects a text string. That's the solution, thanks!